# Create Microsoft Word document from C++ in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, ms-word, visual-c++-2005

We got a homework assignment to create a Microsoft Word document using Visual Studio 2005 and C++. Could anyone explain how this could be done. I was trying to do it using VSTO, but I've had no luck. All resources on the internet I could find explain how this could be done in VB or C#, but I need some C++ examples.
Thanks

**EDIT:** Accepted format is .doc.

Comment: What format(s) are acceptable for the Word document?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [VSTO is not available for C++](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=391270).

Does this MSDN article help?:

- [Embed and Automate a Word Document by Using C++ .NET and MFC](https://web.archive.org/web/20090605190112/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316207)

Comment: But is is possible to do this in some other way?

Comment: links are not working now

Comment: Replaced the second link with archived copy from Wayback Machine.  First link may be gone forever

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Use OLE Automation from a C Application Rather Than C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181473). That will show you the plain way to access the OLE automation interface for Word.

For methods, properties, use the *Object Browser* which you can access by selecting *Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic Editor*. Press `F2` to invoke the object browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Mircosoft Office's Primary Interop Assemblies. Doing this with C++ is not as difficult as it seems. you need to turn on Common Language Runtime support from project properties and then you can simply do a `#using statement` on the Mircosoft.Office.Interop.dll.

After that you should be OK to use the interop assembly as you want. In C++, you access .NET classes a little different i.e., replacing . with :: Something like...

`Microsoft::Office::Interop::Word^ wordObj = new Microsoft::Office::Interop::Word();`

[Microsoft Office 2003 PIAs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3C9A983A-AC14-4125-8BA0-D36D67E0F4AD&displaylang=en)

[Microsoft Office 2007 PIAs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=59DAEBAA-BED4-4282-A28C-B864D8BFA513&displaylang=en)

Comment: C++ and C++/CLI are really two separate languages (although they are similar). As this is a homework assignment I presume the answer needs to be in pure C++. (Not -1ing this just in case the OP just needs to get something done any way he can, in which case your answer could still be helpful.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a spec of the binary Word document format. You could easily roll your own implementation.

http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/OfficeBinaryFormats.mspx

Comment: It should be made more clear that this answer is sarcasm.  A lot of clever people have spent a lot of time trying to reimplement the .doc format.  Doing this for a homework assignment would be non-trivial.

Comment: An article by Joel explaining why this would be a rather bad idea: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Comment: This is not sarcasm. He did not originally note what the requirements were - whether to use another library or not.

Comment: Hehe... Whenever my free-software-adoring workmates have trouble with the way some enormous program (e.g. Firefox) works, I always like to remind them that they're free to make any changes they want since the source code is available -- all X million lines of it :)

Comment: I like the proposed answer though!